# How to Remove UNCHECKED Term Attached in Email Subject Area When Received

Tags: email-server, amavis, email

How do I turn off "UNCHECKED contents in mail FROM" mails sent by Amavis to the postmaster of the domain every time a user sends an encrypted mail. The setup is a Debian 7 with postfix and amavisd.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the parameter `%admin_maps_by_ccat` to define whom amavisd-new sends Mails for each of its categories. With `undef` you can disable the mails.

So you have to define a setting like the following if you don't want to get mails for all "unchecked" mails:

```
$admin_maps_by_ccat{+CC_UNCHECKED} =  undef;
```

To only do this for `UNCHECKED-ENCRYPTED` use this (for amavis 2.9.0, found via release notes):

```
$admin_maps_by_ccat{+CC_UNCHECKED.',1'} = undef;
```

Comment: While this works it appears it disables notifications for any unchecked messages, which also includes messages that exceed size limits or contain corrupt archives in attachments.  From a brief look at the code I couldn't see an obvoius way to distinguish UncheckedEncrypted from simply Unchecked.  Any ideas?

Comment: @JinnKo I think I found a way, see my (pending) edit above.

Answer (score 2):

The problem of receiving emails having ***UNCHECKED*** in the subject can be resolved in two fashions.

The first solution is a temporary and quick fix which can lead to other unwanted problems since mails will not be scanned. Let's us look at what has been proposed so far.

The usage of "`$admin_maps_by_ccat{+CC_UNCHECKED} =  undef;`" as mentioned above should not be used because that solution does not really address the real problem which is stemming from clamav being outdated. Please be aware that once clamav is OUTDATED, the "UNCHECKED" term in the email subject will be attached once more because emails sent by clients can not be scanned properly by clamav that is not updated.

Another aspect of solution one is to add in the file "`/etc/amavis/conf.d/50-user`"  the snippet, "`$undecipherable_subject_tag=undef;`" without the quotation marks of course, as proposed by some individulas. Still, THAT IS NOT A SOLUTION for the same reason mentioned above.

Let's look at solution number two.

First run the command freshclam. Doing so will generate most likely more than one error but will also tell you the latest clamav version. To have a much better output of the problem, run if need be:

```
tail -20 /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log
```

Second, Uninstall the old version with the command:

```
apt remove clamav
```

Third, download the latest clamav file with the command:

```
wget https://www.clamav.net/downloads/production/clamav-0.100.1.tar.gz
```

Here I am using clamav-0.100.1 as an example. Please choose the latest version

Fourth, extract the file with the command:

```
tar xf clamav*
```

Then make sure that you are in the clamav directory. So, run the command:

```
cd clamav*/
```

Now let's compile clamav with the following three commands one by one in the clamav directory:

```
./configure

make

make install
```

Once more  run the command:

```
freshclam
```

If you get the error “`Can’t open/parse the config file /usr/local/etc/freshclam.cong`", here is how to fix it.

Remove the existing `freshclam.conf` file from the `/usr/local/etc/` folder with the command:

```
rm -f /usr/local/etc/freshclam.conf
```

If the file is not there, proceed to the next step below by creating a link to the new file so that if you ever have to run it again, the conf file will stay updated.

```
ln -s /etc/clamav/freshclam.conf /usr/local/etc/freshclam.conf
```

Then run freshclam to update.

```
freshclam
```

Well, there is one more minor error you will get because freshclam is already running in the background. let's kill it with the command:

```
pkill -15 -x freshclam
```

Finally, run freshclam again as follows:

```
freshclam
```

Voila.

To test, send yourself an email or ask a friend to send you an email. You should not see the ***UNCHECKED*** term in the subject of the emails sent from clients. If one week later you have the same error, most likely clamav is upgraded to a newer version.

Comment: **Don't**. 1st, the question was regarding emails that are unchecked because they are encrypted, which has nothing to do with an outdated clamav. 2nd, you propose to replace the clamav installed from the Debian repository with a manually installed version. This means you will always have to update it manually, which is a lot of work and at some point you will stop and run an insecure system. Instead, upgrade your Debian to the latest stable release (currently Stretch) and make sure to add the stable-updates repository (currently stretch-updates). It currently includes the latest ClamAV 0.100.1

Comment: So running Debian Stretch, upgrade your clamav like this: Add `deb     http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main` into `/etc/apt/sources.list` (if it is not there yet). Run `apt update` and `apt-upgrade` and you are should get the latest clamav. Read https://wiki.debian.org/StableUpdates and see https://packages.debian.org/stretch-updates/clamav

Comment: Installing clamav will not help if your problem is that clamav can't check archives because they are encrypted. While this answer is very good in both volume and clarity, it does not solve the original problem.

Also getting the current clamav archive from your distribution is always the better choice, don't install stuff manually unless you have loads of time maintaining this manual installation.