# How to modify admin_maps_by_ccat amavisd settings for Zimbra OSE 8.5?

Tags: postfix, zimbra, amavis

I'm trying to apply this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/539279/turn-of-amavisd-notifications-about-unchecked-content-to-postmaster) to my zimbra installation as I'm getting a postmaster email every time I send an encrypted email.

I tried adding 
`$admin_maps_by_ccat{+CC_UNCHECKED} =  undef;` to /opt/zimbra/conf/amavisd.conf and `zmamavisdctl stop; zmamavisdctl start` but it just removes the directive from the configuration file.

Any assistance greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For permanent solution, you should edit `/opt/zimbra/conf/amavisd.conf.in` not `/opt/zimbra/conf/amavisd.conf`.

The `/opt/zimbra/conf/amavisd.conf.in` was template for `/opt/zimbra/conf/amavisd.conf`, so if you restart amavisd, zimbra will overwrite the `amavisd.conf` based on `amavisd.conf.in`.

PS: If you curious about how `zmamavisdctl`, take a look of its source code

```
# less /opt/zimbra/bin/zmamavisdctl
```